# Windows command-line to list all folders without current and parent directories?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, directory-listing

What's the Windows command-line to list all folders without current and parent directories? Something similar to `ls -A` in Linux

Comment: dir /ah lists hidden folders / files where you are.

Comment: Give a try `dir "c:\" /s /ah /b` and see if that does what you want for listing the hidden ones only.

Comment: `dir /b` is the closest to `ls -A` but the output will be 1 file or directory per line not as unix with multiple entries on enach line

Comment: @John `dir /ah` will only list hiddens files and not system files without hidden attribute

Answer (score 1):

`ls -A` lists all files and directories and not just folders

It's a lot trickier to do that in cmd. `dir /ah` will list files/folders that have the *hidden* attribute so you'll miss files that have only *system* attribute. You'll need to get system files separately with `dir /as`, and also normal folders with `dir` because folders without any attributes won't be displayed in `dir /ah` and `dir /as`. For more information run `dir /?` or read the [`dir` documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir)

Then comes the issue of combining the result. In Windows 10 `sort` has a new `/unique` flag so you can use the following command to get the desired result

```bat
(dir /ah & dir /as & dir) | sort /unique
```

You can also use `(dir /b /ah & dir /b /as & dir /b) | sort /unique` to get a saner result. In older Windows you're on your own to remove the duplicate entries

It's better to use PowerShell. Just run either of these

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Force
Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory,Hidden,System
```

or their abbreviated versions

```powershell
ls -Fo
ls -At D,H,S
```

You can call them from cmd like this `powershell -Command "Get-ChildItem -Attributes Directory,Hidden,System"` or `powershell -c "ls -Fo"`. For more information about the command read [`Get-ChildItem`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7)